# Jquery .html() doesn't update an element with X, but then calling .html() on it returns X

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I'm working on a rails application and building a 'follow/unfollow' feature. When a (un)follow button is clicked, a js file is called to rerender a partial. The Jquery .html() function is somehow failing to  update an element on the screen and in the Inspect Element tool, but calling .html() on that updated element outputs what should be the new html content. I'm not sure where to go next with debugging..

_job_info.html.haml partial:

```
.job_info
  //..stuff..
  .right{id: "bookmark-job-#{job.id}"}
    = render partial: 'jobs/bookmark_job', locals: { job: job }
```

_bookmark_job.html.haml Partial:

```
- bookmarked = current_user.following?(job)
- if bookmarked
  = link_to '', unfollow_job_path(job), class: 'bookmarked-job', data: { remote: true, method: :post }
- else
  = link_to '', follow_job_path(job), class: 'add-bookmark-job', data: { remote: true, method: :post }
```

JS action _follow.js.erb:

```
console.log('<%= @job.id %>');   // This fires and outputs the correct ID
$('#bookmark-job-<%= @job.id %>').html('<%= j(render(partial: 'jobs/bookmark_job', locals: { job: @job })) %>');  // **

$('#jobs_companies').html('<%= j(render(partial: 'nav/following_info')) %>');   // This correctly updates a user info section
```

BEFORE FIRING an unfollow action:

Partial HTML (from Inspect Element)

```
<div class="right" id="bookmark-job-1">
  <a class="bookmarked-job" data-method="post" data-remote="true" href="/jobs/1/unfollow"></a>
</div>
```

$('#bookmark-job-1').html() console output for the element: (spacing intact)

```
"
                              <a class="bookmarked-job" data-method="post" data-remote="true" href="/jobs/1/unfollow"></a>
                            "
```

AFTER FIRING the unfollow action & .html() update:

The second line here is supposed to change the HTML of that element. After it is fired, the screen and the 'Elements' view in the inspector show no change. BUT using the console to call $('#bookmark-job-1') does return the updated HTML.

Partial HTML (from Inspect Element) => Remains unchanged, same as above. 
$('#bookmark-job-1').html() console output for the element after update: (spacing intact)

```
"<a class="add-bookmark-job" data-method="post" data-remote="true" href="/jobs/1/follow"></a>
"
```

The controller portion of this is all working fine. The actions are called, the correct @job is set and passed to the partial. The DB updates and even the 2nd .html call in the js action works to update the new 'followed' count.

```
class JobsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_job, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy, :follow, :unfollow]

  def index
    @jobs = Job.where("id < ?", 10)

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.js # for js template
    end
  end
  def follow
    current_user.follow @job
  end
  def unfollow
    current_user.stop_following @job
  end

  private
    def set_job
      @job = Job.find(params[:id])
    end
end
```

Other Misc info:
- App is Rails 4.1.4 on Ruby 2.0.0
- This follow feature is built using the 'acts_as_follower' gem

What could cause the .html('new') method to not update an element, but appear as if it did when .html() is called on that element?

Comment: All I can suggest is to verify that the element you are looking at actually has that css id?

Comment: Thanks and yes the id is matching. The before & after console logs of $('#bookmark-job-1').html() are showing a change, it's just not reflected on the screen or Inspector.

Comment: i have the same problem, but only happens on IE, in chrome it works fine